# Shell скрипт. Как создать Alias на самого себя?

Tags: bash, shell, скрипт

Необходимо чтобы скрипт сам запихал себя в alias для текущего пользователя. отредактировать .bashrc то мы из скрипта можем, а обновить список alias нет.
Идеальное поведение скрипта:
- первый запуск sh script (alias sc добавляется)
- повторные запуски уже как sc

---

Добавляю с помощью shell скрипта алиас:

```
echo "alias sc='sh ~/script.sh'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

После чего следует запустить сам сценарий bashrc, чтобы изменения вступили в силу до перезагрузки.
Если выполнить:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Ничего не произойдет, т.к. файлик просто включится в скрипт. 
Собственно вопрос, как обновить список алиасов из скрипта?

```
alias alias_command_name='commands'
```

Не поможет, т.к. он будет работать только для текущей сессии.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: запуская скрипт, вы создаёте новый процесс. этот процесс никак не сможет повлиять на ваш «основной» процесс оболочки.

Comment: Тогда в чем вопрос, Для каждого пользователья создается отдельный .bashrc со своими алиасами.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант.  создать переменую и смотреть чему равна переменая. и добавлять алиас

```
if [ {run:-0} -eq 0 ]
  then
    export run=1
    alias sc='sh ~/script.sh' 
  else
```

И не советую добавлять строку в .bashrc иначе при многократных запусках, у вас будет множество добавленых строк

Comment: Чтобы не было дублей проверяем: if ! grep "alias sc" ~/.bashrc > /dev/null . Если я вас верно понял, вы предлагаете разместить данный кусок кода в bashrc, но каким образом мы передадим туда переменную?

Comment: этот блок размешается в .bashrc и при первом запуске здесь создается переменая run , при повторном запуске перемная уже есть и это блок будет игнорироватся.   Ну да если bash будет запускатся из одного сеанса . то будет работать . Но если в разных сеансах то нет